# How to generate type hierarchy diagrams with Scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I want that Scaladoc generates a type hierarchy diagram for the following code snippet:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
```

But when I execute `scaladoc <file>.scala` there is no type hierarchy shown - neither in `A` nor in `B`. How can I generate such diagrams?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, one needs Scaladoc2 for this, which is part of Scala 2.10.

If 2.10 is installed, one also needs to pass the `-diagrams` option to Scaladoc in order to generate the diagrams. But if you do so it can be that the following error message occurs:

```
Graphviz dot encountered an error when generating the diagram for:
_root_
These are usually spurious errors, but if you notice a persistant error on
a diagram, please use the -diagrams-debug flag and report a bug with the output.
Graphviz will be restarted...
```

The error occurs because Scaladoc does not generate the diagrams by itself but tries to call [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), to do this job. When we add the `-diagrams-debug` flag we well get among other things the exact error message:

```
The following is the log of the failure:
  Main thread in _root_: Exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dot": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

To solve the problem one needs to install the program `dot`, which is part of Graphviz. After doing so one should be able to execute `scaladoc -diagrams <file>.scala` successfully and see as a result the tag "Type Hierarchy" above the member search bar in the generated documentation.

Executing `scaladoc -help` shows further information for the diagrams option:

```
  -diagrams                                   Create inheritance diagrams for classes, traits and packages.
  -diagrams-dot-path <path>                   The path to the dot executable used to generate the inheritance diagrams. Eg: /usr/bin/dot
  -diagrams-dot-restart <n>                   The number of times to restart a malfunctioning dot process before disabling diagrams (default: 5)
  -diagrams-dot-timeout <n>                   The timeout before the graphviz dot util is forcefully closed, in seconds (default: 10)
  -diagrams-max-classes <n>                   The maximum number of superclasses or subclasses to show in a diagram
  -diagrams-max-implicits <n>                 The maximum number of implicitly converted classes to show in a diagram
```