# How to generate hierarchy/UML diagram with Play 2.2.x?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, scaladoc, typesafe-activator

I know you can use [scaladoc itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435474/how-to-generate-type-hierarchy-diagrams-with-scaladoc) to generate hierarchy diagrams but how do I use `play doc` to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add following line to the `build.sbt` to have diagrams generated by the way of `doc` task.

```
scalacOptions in Compile in doc += "-diagrams"
```

If you'd like, you can pass arbitrary parameters, like for example

```
scalacOptions in Compile in doc ++= Seq("-diagrams", "-diagrams-max-classes", "30")
```

PS. Make sure that you have the `dot` program installed.