# Display graph of trait dependency for heavily cake pattern scala and sbt program

Tags: scala, graphics, dependency-injection, sbt, cake-pattern

Before i try to make a manual graph of dependency (using inkscape) to resume all possibility for my [scala program](https://github.com/openmole/mgo) which use **heavily** cake pattern, i ask question here.

Is there a best and simple way to automaticaly cartography a complex hierarchy of trait dependency in a scala program which use Cake Pattern (or Dependency injection) ?

Any SBT, scala or other existing library ?

Comment: Have you tried to generate scaladoc docs with type hierarchy diagrams? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435474/how-to-generate-type-hierarchy-diagrams-with-scaladoc

Comment: O, this is better than nothing, i need to clic on the different classes to obtain information .. perhaps an option draw an entire graph tree ?