# Scaladoc diagrams

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

Is it possible to generate diagrams with Scaladoc and SBT?

I tried to add this line in my `build.sbt`:

`scalacOptions in (Compile,doc) := Seq("-diagrams", "-diagrams-debug")`

But I receive:
    Diagram generation running time breakdown:

```
diagrams model filtering
========================
count:        242 items
total time:   0 ms
average time: 0 ms
maximum time: 0 ms

diagrams model generation
=========================
count:        242 items
total time:   45 ms
average time: 0 ms
maximum time: 11 ms

dot diagram generation
======================
count:        89 items
total time:   24 ms
average time: 0 ms
maximum time: 3 ms

dot process runnning
====================
count:        89 items
total time:   590 ms
average time: 6 ms
maximum time: 512 ms

svg processing
==============
count:        89 items
total time:   269 ms
average time: 3 ms
maximum time: 88 ms

Broken images: 238
Fixed images: 0
```

How can I get more logs about the "Broken images"?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The command `last` shows me:

```
[debug] Calling Scaladoc with arguments:
[debug]         -diagrams
[debug]         -diagrams-debug
[debug]         -d
[debug]         /.../target/scala-2.10/api
[debug]         -bootclasspath
[debug]         /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/classes:/home/thibaud/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar
[debug]         -classpath
... my classpath and my classes
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[success] Total time: 18 s, completed 23 oct. 2015 15:10:32
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13435475/3165552) describes that [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) must be installed in order to make this work properly, although the provided information doesn't contain any hint on this behalf, maybe this is already the cause of the problem?

Comment: Graphviz is installed on my computer and I can run `dot` from the command line

Comment: I guess you can not easily get more logs. Digging into [scala.tools.nsc.doc.html.page.diagram.DotDiagramGenerator](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/page/diagram/DotDiagramGenerator.scala) and DiagramStats from the same package: from line 388 of DotDiagramGenerator and the generated diagrams one can gain the following insight: dot seems to sometimes forget to include the little `c`s, `o`s and `t`s to the left of a template name in the diagrams resulting in an increased broken image count.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to generate diagrams with Scaladoc and SBT?

Since this is one of more highly voted questions tagged `sbt`, I'll try to answer it. I tried using Scala 2.11.8 and 2.12.0-M4, but neither worked for me. There are some problems with Scaladoc diagram generation itself, not sbt. See for example [SI-7950: Running ScalaDoc with -diagram fails on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7950). I also tried running `scaladoc` directly, and I still get the similar error messages.

One theory I've heard is that scaladoc is too sensitive to `dot` warning messages. So there's been a hack of wrapping `dot` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/dot "$@" 2> >( grep -v  "CoreText performance note:" >&2 )
```

Using the above script did not work for me. So likely it's not possible at this time.